# Cannot initialise store from localStorage on App initialization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm struggling to initialize my Vuex store with the account details of the logged in user from `localStorage`.

I've been through as many examples as I can of Auth using Nuxt, and none of them demonstrate how on the client side to pull an `authToken` from `localStorage` to re-use with subsequent API requests when the user refreshes the page or navigates to the App

Disclaimer: I'm not using Nuxt in SSR (this might affect your answer).

What is annoying is that I *can* actually load from `localStorage` and initialize my state but then it gets overwritten. I'll show you what I mean with this small code example:

```
buildInitialState () {
   if (!process.server) {
      // Query the localStorage and return accessToken, refreshToken and account details
      return {accessToken: <valid-string>, refreshToken: <valid-string>, account: <valid-json-blob>}
   } else {
      // Return "empty map", we use the string "INVALID" for demonstration purposes.
     return {accessToken: "INVALID", refreshToken: "INVALID", account: "INVALID"}
  }
}

export const state = () => buildInitialState()
```

If I put a breakpoint on `buildInitialState` I can see that I correctly initialize the state with the value of `localStorage`, i.e. I get the `accessToken` and `refreshToken`, etc.. back.

All seems well.

But *then* .....in another part of the program I'm using Axois to send requests, and I use an axios interceptor to decorate the request with the `accessToken`. To do this I have to stick it into a plugin to get access to the `store`.

Something like so:

```
export default ({ app, store }) => {
  axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    const accessToken = _.get(store.state, ['account', 'accessToken'])
    if (accessToken) {
      config.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = accessToken
    }
    return config
  }, (error) => Promise.reject(error))
}
```

Here the `store` is closed over in the arrow function supplied to `axios` so when I go to send the request it sees if there is a valid `accessToken`, and if so then use it.

BUT, and here's the kicker, when a request is made, I look at the `store.state.account.accessToken` and low and behold its been *reinitialized* back to the value of "INVALID".

What? Que?

It's almost like the store was *reinitialized* behind the scenes? Or somehow the `state` in the plugin is "server side state"?? because if I try and log `buildInitialState` I don't get any messages indicating that the path that produced a map with `INVALID` is being run.

Basically, I don't thoroughly understand the initialization pathway Nuxt is taking here at all.

If any Nuxt masters could help me out understand this a bit more that would be great, it's turning into a bit of a show stopper for me.

Essentially! All I want to be able to do is save the user so that when they refresh their page we can keep on running without forcing them to re-login again....I thought that would be simple.

Thanks and regards, Jason.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this with a bit of experimentation and comments from other posters around what is called SSR and SPA.

Firstly, this https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1500 thread really helped me and the final comment from @jsonberry steered my mind in the right direction, away from `fetch` and `asyncData`.

I finally had a bit more of an understanding of how `NUXT.j`s was separating SSR and SPA calls.

I then tried @robyedlin suggestion of putting localStorage initialization in the `created()` method for my main `layout/default.vue` page.

While I made progress with that suggestion it turns out `created()` is also called SSR and I was still trying to initialize my store from credentials that weren't accessible.

Finally, moving the initialization to mounted() did the trick!

So in summary:

- My account store is left alone, I don't try and initialize it when it is created (it's just overwritten at some point when the SSR stuff runs)
- On `mounted()` in `layout/defualt.vue` I read from `localStorage` and initialize the account store so I can start making API requests with the appropriate accessToken.

That seems to have done the trick.